# JavaScript link change from article (script block page)

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

on my page i want to convert all links from some article, so i make a simple script but when i add it in wordpress its block page, like it have infinite loop... (im sorry on my bad English).

Script need to get all links from some area (some div)... if someone can find problem, please help!

This is script:

```
if(document.getElementById("somediv")){
    dwn=document.getElementById("somediv");
    link=dwn.getElementsByTagName("a");
    count=link.length;
    i=0;
        while(i<count){
            hotornot=String(link[i]);
                if(hotornot.indexOf("auto-im.com")=="-1"){
                link[i].href="http://newpage.me/seo?dwn="+escape(link[i]);
                i++;}
                };  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(hotornot.indexOf("auto-im.com")=="-1"){
    link[i].href="http://newpage.me/seo?dwn="+escape(link[i]);
i++;}
```

That's your problem. i will never increment to the total number of links on the page, since you're filtering by auto-im.com. Put the i++ outside the conditional.